# SQL could not insert zero width space char

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, encoding

Somehow my html page has `&#8203;` - `Zero width space` character and I am sending it to DB to store in one column.

Now my one DB accepts this value while other DB instance throws error

`incorrect string value \xe2\x80\x8b for HEADER column`

Both DB's schema and Tables have collation as `latin 1 - Default` and the columns have Collation as `table default`. Even tried with setting column's collation as `utf8 - Default Collation` - still same issue.

P.S. I am using Hibernate for DB operations.

```
 Exception

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch updateorg.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(....
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch updateorg.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140).....

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8B\xE2\x80\x8B...' for column 'LEFT_TEXT' at row
```

Comment: Post error  hibernate message  and hibernate logs for further clarifications..

Comment: [Latin 1 is an one byte character set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449336/utf-8-vs-latin1) so an Unicode symbol `&#8203` (two bytes here) isn't from Latin 1 character set.

Comment: I have updated collation of particular column to `utf8 - Default collation` and still an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got the answer for this.

Though my collation was `utf8` i have to set char set to `utf8`.

using `alter table schema.table-name convert to character set utf8;`