# LEFT JOIN is fast but RIGHT JOIN is slow even though the same indexes are on both tables

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have two tables, both with around 200,000 records. I want to join them on KEY which is a string.

Both tables have an index KEY, VALUE. When I run:

```
   SELECT vpn, t1_sku, t2_sku 
     FROM first_inventory 
LEFT JOIN second_inventory USING (vpn)
```

It is really fast. Here is the explain output:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | id | select_type | table            | type     | possible_keys   | key     | key_len   | ref     | rows   | Extra        |
 |----|-------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|---------|-----------|---------|--------|--------------|
 | 1  | SIMPLE      | first_inventory  | index    |                 | t1_vpn  | 158       |         | 204437 | Using index  |
 | 1  | SIMPLE      | second_inventory | ref      | t2_vpn          | t2_vpn  | 387       | func    | 1      | Using index  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I do a RIGHT JOIN it takes forever and never finishes: "SELECT vpn, t1_sku, t2_sku FROM first_inventory RIGHT JOIN second_inventory USING (vpn)". Here is the explain output:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | id | select_type | table            | type     | possible_keys   | key     | key_len   | ref     | rows   | Extra        |
 |----|-------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|---------|-----------|---------|--------|--------------|
 | 1  | SIMPLE      | second_inventory | index    |                 | t1_vpn  | 773       |         | 220996 | Using index  |
 | 1  | SIMPLE      | first_inventory  | index    |                 | t2_vpn  | 158       |         | 204437 | Using index  |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can see that the `RIGHT JOIN` query appears to be looking at 220996 x 204437 rows, while the `LEFT JOIN` only seems to be looking at 204437 rows, but I can't figure out why since I've made the same indexes on both tables.

At the end of both tables it says:

```
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 't1_vpn' ('vpn','t1_sku') USING BTREE
and
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 't2_vpn' ('vpn','t2_sku') USING BTREE
```

Any idea why the RIGHT JOIN query is taking so long?

Comment: Do you get the same issue (only the other way around) if you switch the order of the tables in the FROM statement?

Comment: It was hard to line up the values from the EXPLAINs with the formatting... I've edited but pls. check to make sure I've put things in the right place.  Especially because it looks like there were some blank fields.

Comment: Thanks for reformatting, PeteGO! Yes, I do get the same issue the other way around when I switch the order of the tables in the FROM statement.

Comment: Notice how `type` value EXPLAIN shows is different, `index` and `ref` in the first example vs two times `index` in the second one? Have you looked up what those mean yet?

Comment: Post an image of the full execution plan, that will help. Also maybe can try keeping it as a left join but just swap your table name (same effect as right join).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about "full execution plan." I did an explain extended and saw that there was a warning. I looked at the warnings and saw that the join was converting UTF8 content. Switched all the content to latin1 and it's all running really fast now.

Comment: Curiously, the clue what was the 'func' keyword, but that would imply that the 2nd query was faster! It might be useful to show those 'warnings' so others can figure out what's really going on.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  Something funny may be going on with datatypes and other things.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was UTF-8 content in one of the tables. I changed everything to Latin1 and it runs fast both ways now.

See: [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449336/utf-8-vs-latin1http://)